# merge() dataset 1 to columns of dataset 2 in R Error in .(id,y1):could not find function "

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to merge a dataset 1 and columns from dataset 2 but I am getting a weird error.

```
data1 <- data.frame(id = 1:6,                                  # Create first example data frame
                    x1 = c(5, 1, 4, 9, 1, 2),
                    x2 = c("A", "Y", "G", "F", "G", "Y"))
 
data2 <- data.frame(id = 4:9,                                  # Create second example data frame
                    y1 = c(3, 3, 4, 1, 2, 9),
                    y2 = c("a", "x", "a", "x", "a", "x"))

data_merge <- merge(data1, data2[,.(id,y1)], by = "id)
```

**Error in .(id,y1) : could not find function "."**

Comment: how should your target data frame look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is just a `data.frame` and not a `data.table`.  So, we need the usual selection of columns with `c`

```
data2[c('id', 'y1')]
```

The syntax in OP's code would work if it is converted to `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data2)
```